# How can I restrict the number of objects created for a single class in C++?

Tags: c++, class

*eg: (I want to restrict 10 objects for one class).*

```
         class base{
               /--------/
         };
           void main()
           {
           base a1;
           base a2;
           -------
           base a10;
           base a11//Error
         }
```

Comment: what should happen when the 11th object is created? runtime error is fine?

Comment: Yes that's fine

Comment: Just a sample code if you have some other idea always welcome

Comment: Let the class constructor increment a static counter until it reaches your limit and throw an exception if it exceeds the limit.

Comment: @vahancho ...and, be sure that copy-elision is effective. ;-)

Answer (score 3):

You can add a `static` member that will be the counter of the class instances. When the counter exceeds 10, you throw an exception (runtime error) and the job is done.

For example:

```
class MyClass
{
   private:
      static unsigned int count;
      //...

      void check_count()
      {
         if(++count > 10)
            throw MyException("Error: Too many instances of MyClass created"); //MyException being your own exception class (deriving for std::exception)
      }

   public:
      MyClass()
      {
         check_count();
         //...
      }
      MyClass(const MyClass & mc)
      {
         check_count();
         //...
      }
      ~MyClass
      {
         --count;
      }
};

unsigned int MyClass::count = 0; //Initialize the counter to zero
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `static` member to count the number of object of the class is created:

```
#include <iostream>

class base {
    static int counter;

public:
    base() {
        if (counter > 10) {
            throw("Error: Object creation exceeded.");
        }

        std::cout << "Object " << (counter + 1) << " created." << std::endl;
        counter++;
    }
};

int base::counter = 0;

int main(void) {
    try {
        for (int i = 0; i <= 20; i++) {
            base b;
        }
    } catch (const char *e) {
        std::cout << e << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Notice that the `for` tries to loop till `20` but it quits at `11` since the exception is thrown from the 11th class constructor.

That outputs:

```
Object 1 created.
Object 2 created.
Object 3 created.
Object 4 created.
Object 5 created.
Object 6 created.
Object 7 created.
Object 8 created.
Object 9 created.
Object 10 created.
Object 11 created.
Error: Object creation exceeded.
```